# Can Transcendental meditation be used in lab setting via Digital instructor or do we need a practitioner for TM?

Tags: meditation

I am starting my thesis, and as I was doing research on types of meditations effect on self compassion. I am new to this research, so I had wanted to know from anyone with experience. Someone, who has carried a research regarding Transcendental meditation. I want to know if for using TM for my research, will I need a practitioner or I can use a certified youtube video, where the digital instructor will be enough to guide my participants for TM?

Answer (score 5):

As per the [official site](https://www.tm.org):

> The TM technique is not "one size fits all." It's taught one-on-one
>   and is carefully personalized for you.
>
> Only certified TM teachers can instruct you in the authentic TM
>   technique.

You could, obviously, perform some form of meditation that you consider equivalent to it. However, you won't be able to claim that you are testing the authentic TM, which is, in general quite secretive regarding the concrete process.

There are TM dropouts who claim to reveal the whole process, like this [guideline](http://minet.org/Documents/TM-FAQ). Performing upon these also carries the risk of being considered 'not the authentic TM.'